# Create a new array from .filter()

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects,

```
[
   {name: 'Bob', age: 22, hidden: false },
   {name: 'Jessica', age: 60, hidden: false },
   {name: 'Marley', age: 34, hidden: true },
   {name: 'Michella', age: 12, hidden: false },
   {name: 'Sam', age: 10, hidden: true }
]
```

What I am wanting to do is get an array of names but I only want that name if `hidden:false` so the end result would look like, `['Bob', 'Jessica', 'Michella']`

If I do,

```
const names = myArray.filter((array) => {
    if(array.hidden) {
        return array.name
    }
});
```

Then I get the objects in an array that are not hidden, but I cannot workout how to filter the objects to just get an array of names? I am using filter correctly?

Comment: "*I am using filter correctly?*" no, `.filter()` ***only*** filters the array. From array with multiple items, you get an array with potentially less items. That's it. That's filtering. It doesn't *also* do transformation as that's a separate operation which isn't filtering.

Comment: `myArray.filter(array => array.hidden)` to get only the objects with hidden. Then use `map()` to get only the names: `myArray.filter(array => array.hidden).map(array => array.name)`

Comment: Do the `.filter()` first and then use `.map()` to transform the filtered array of objects into an array of strings (the names).

Comment: Just use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to combine both actions `[].reduce((previous, current) => {!current.hidden && previous.push(current.name); return previous}, [])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [**array.filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with desired condition check `!hidden` and [**array.map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the names of the user.

```js
const data = [
   {name: 'Bob', age: 22, hidden: false },
   {name: 'Jessica', age: 60, hidden: false },
   {name: 'Marley', age: 34, hidden: true },
   {name: 'Michella', age: 12, hidden: false },
   {name: 'Sam', age: 10, hidden: true }
];

const names = data.filter(({hidden}) => !hidden).map(({name}) => name)

console.log(names);
```